How to bind two sf objects based on matching values in one column in r
I have two sf objects. The first has one object with 3 variables and the second 2 objects with 3 variables. The data looks like this:
Table 1
| River     | length | geometry |
| ------    | ------ | -------- |
| River1    | 7.29   | Multilinestring

Table 2
| River    | length  | geometry   |
| -------- | ------- | -------     |
| River1   |  7.29   | Multilinestring
| River2   |  7.68   | Multilinestring

Objective
Bind these two tables to one. There should be 2 objects with 4 variables. The result should look like this:
| River    | length | geometry        | length1
| -------- | -- --- |------       ----|-------|
| River1   | 7,29   | Multilinestring | 7,29  |
| River2   | NA     | Multilinestring | 7,68  |

Adding another column with River2 to Table 1 is not an option as the original data has much more columns. Table1 is also in the original data the one with fewer columns.
What I already tried
bind_cols(Table1, Table2)

st_join(Table1, Table2)


Which geometry do you want in the output or are they the same? Are you joining on the "River" column?

Given these two sample objects:
> t1
Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 2 fields
Geometry type: LINESTRING
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 1 ymin: 6 xmax: 5 ymax: 10
CRS:           NA
   River length                       geometry
1 River1   7.29 LINESTRING (1 6, 2 7, 3 8, ...

> t2
Simple feature collection with 2 features and 2 fields
Geometry type: LINESTRING
Dimension:     XY, XYZ
Bounding box:  xmin: 1 ymin: 6 xmax: 5 ymax: 10
z_range:       zmin: NA zmax: NA
CRS:           NA
   River length                       geometry
1 River1   7.29 LINESTRING (1 6, 2 7, 3 8, ...
2 River2   7.68 LINESTRING Z (1 6 11, 2 7 1...

You need to "merge" on the "River" column, but you can't do "merge" on two sf objects, so drop the geometry from the joined one:
> merge(t2, 
   st_drop_geometry(t1),
   by="River", all=TRUE, suffixes=c("1",""))

Simple feature collection with 2 features and 3 fields
Geometry type: LINESTRING
Dimension:     XY, XYZ
Bounding box:  xmin: 1 ymin: 6 xmax: 5 ymax: 10
z_range:       zmin: NA zmax: NA
Projected CRS: OSGB36 / British National Grid
   River length1 length                       geometry
1 River1    7.29   7.29 LINESTRING (1 6, 2 7, 3 8, ...
2 River2    7.68     NA LINESTRING Z (1 6 11, 2 7 1...

(note that at some point I set the CRS of t2 and it is preserved in the output so that's all good)

Just to contribute some additionally terminology (besides bind & merge): Wouldn't this simply be a "join", e.g. dplyr::full_join()?

"join" is SQL terminology, "merge" has been an R function and therefore R terminology since maybe 25 years ago, and is implemented in base. dplyr is not needed for sf.

I get your point - but people being used to general GIS terminology (c.f. ArcGIS/QGIS) might rather recognize the verb "join". Just saying. The nice thing about this is, many roads lead to rome.

Feel free to write an answer using whatever code you want and then the OP can accept their "best"?
